# Repeating Background in Cocos2D 2.0 turns sprite black

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, repeat

I'm having trouble getting an image to repeat indefinitely as I scroll it along my screen in Cocos2d 2.0... I'm using the ccTexParams method like so:

```
_movingHills = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"MenuBackHills.png"];
_movingHills.position = backGround.position;
[self addChild:_movingHills z:1];

//make sure hills repeat!

ccTexParams repeatHills = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE};
[_movingHills.texture setTexParameters:&repeatHills];
```

and then in update:

```
float PIXELS_PER_SECOND = 1;
static float offset = 0;
offset += PIXELS_PER_SECOND * dt;

CGSize textureSize = _movingHills.textureRect.size;
[_movingHills setTextureRect:CGRectMake(offset, 0, textureSize.width, textureSize.height)];
```

However all this is resulting in is a pitch black screen being added to my scene :/

Comment: If it helps to know or could be anything to do with the reason that this isn't working MenuBackHills has areas of transparency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with getting a single background image to scroll how I wanted it to for a while. I found [this](https://github.com/aramkocharyan/cocos2d), which is very easy to implement and works well. Just copy the files into the cocos2d folder on your project, and follow the short tutorial shown in the link, and everything should work well.

Comment: Thanks I was actually just starting off writing my own class which basically does the same thing as your link :) but I'll mark you correct anyhow :P